# Recursive filtering array of the objects with nesting by specific property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, filter

Here's the array that I got, and my purpose is to filter this whole array of objects and to return an array of object with founded name ( even if it's located in the nested deepest level of children's). For example, If I am filtering by "Model8", the return value of my function has to be = `[{ name: "Model8", type: "file", path: "/path/to/file" }]`

```
const arr = [
  {
    name: "Model",
    type: "directory",
    path: "/path/to/folder",
    children: [
      {
        name: "Model1",
        type: "file",
        path: "/path/to/file",
        children: [
          {
            name: "Model2",
            type: "file",
            path: "/path/to/file",
            children: [
              {
                name: "Model3",
                type: "file",
                path: "/path/to/file",
                children: [
                  { name: "Model4", type: "file", path: "/path/to/file" },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Inventory",
    type: "directory",
    path: "/path/to/folder",
    children: [{ name: "inventory.yaml", type: "file", path: "/path/to/file" }],
  },
  {
    name: "UI",
    type: "directory",
    path: "/path/to/folder",
    children: [
      { name: "elements", type: "directory", path: "/path/to/file" },
      { name: "viewmodel", type: "directory", path: "/path/to/file" },
      { name: "i18n", type: "directory", path: "/path/to/file" },
      {
        name: "index.template.html",
        type: "file",
        path: "/path/to/file",
        children: [
          {
            name: "Model5",
            type: "file",
            path: "/path/to/file",
            children: [
              {
                name: "Model6",
                type: "file",
                path: "/path/to/file",
                children: [
                  {
                    name: "Model7",
                    type: "file",
                    path: "/path/to/file",
                    children: [
                      { name: "Model8", type: "file", path: "/path/to/file" },
                    ],
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  { name: "DeviceConnector", type: "directory", children: [] },
];
```

I've come up with 2 options :

1)

```
function searchFilter(searchVal,arr) {
        const res = arr.filter(function filteredList(el) {
          if (el.children) {
              el.children = el.children.filter(filteredList);
          }
          if (el.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchVal.toLowerCase())) return true;
          return res;
      }); 
    }
    
    searchFilter("Model8",arr)
```

But the main problem right here is that for some reason I can't "access 'res' before initialization"

2)

```
function searchFilter(arr, name) {
  const searchItem = arr.find((i) => i.name === name);
  if (!searchItem) {
    return arr.filter((i) => searchFilter(i.children, name));
  }
  return searchitem;
}
```

And here, I can't get lower than first iterated object of an array. The max depth is the object with "Model3" name property.

Answer (score 1):

We can write a generic function that collects all nested values matching the predicate supplied and then do the name search atop it, like this:

```js
const collect = (pred) => (xs = []) => 
  xs .flatMap (x => [
    ... (pred (x) ? [x] : []),
    ... collect (pred) (x .children)
  ])

const findByName = (target) => 
  collect (({name}) => name == target)

const arr = [{name: "Model", type: "directory", path: "/path/to/folder", children: [{name: "Model1", type: "file", path: "/path/to/file", children: [{name: "Model2", type: "file", path: "/path/to/file", children: [{name: "Model3", type: "file", path: "/path/to/file", children: [{name: "Model4", type: "file", path: "/path/to/file"}]}]}]}]}, {name: "Inventory", type: "directory", path: "/path/to/folder", children: [{name: "inventory.yaml", type: "file", path: "/path/to/file"}]}, {name: "UI", type: "directory", path: "/path/to/folder", children: [{name: "elements", type: "directory", path: "/path/to/file"}, {name: "viewmodel", type: "directory", path: "/path/to/file"}, {name: "i18n", type: "directory", path: "/path/to/file"}, {name: "index.template.html", type: "file", path: "/path/to/file", children: [{name: "Model5", type: "file", path: "/path/to/file", children: [{name: "Model6", type: "file", path: "/path/to/file", children: [{name: "Model7", type: "file", path: "/path/to/file", children: [{name: "Model8", type: "file", path: "/path/to/file"}]}]}]}]}]}, {name: "DeviceConnector", type: "directory", children: []}]

console .log (findByName ('Model8') (arr))
```

We could pass any predicate here.  We can to a case-insensitive comparison, or a substring search, or a combination.  But that's irrelevant to the actual traversal of the tree, so it's useful to have it separated into its own function.

If you really don't like calling like `findByName ('Model8') (arr)` (which I prefer these days, but some don't like), we could rewrite like this:

```js
const findByName = (xs, target) => 
  collect (({name}) => name == target) (xs)

findByName (arr, 'Model8')
```

If we wanted, we could go one step further and pass a function to decide how the children of a node are found.  Here we would just pass `(x) => x .children`, but not every structure we want to use necessarily uses the name `"children"` for this.  That version is left as an exercise for the reader. ;-)